# AWS EMR spark on hadoop with data storage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am new to AWS EMR and trying to create a cluster to process data from S3.

I have a use case where there is incremental data feed into to cluster every hour. Right now I am starting the cluster with Hadoop and spark. Once data is processed I am terminating the cluster.

Is it a valid use case to store data on hadoop and process it with spark? Any links would be great.

Comment: You're not storing data on Hadoop if it's in S3. You're only processing temporary data with YARN

Comment: @cricket_007 is it possible to have s3 as source of iterative data and store/add-on to existing data on hadoop?

Comment: Yes... It's not clear what you think you're using Hadoop for exactly. EMR can read and store data from S3 and process it in memory... Any data thats (temporarily) in HDFS is deleted when the instances are terminated.

Comment: I want to have incremental data to be processed. Log file from day 1 + day 2 if step is executed on day 2. On day 3 data would be Day 1 + day 2 + day 3 logs combined

Comment: I was thinking if I could somehow combine/join dataset outside or inside cluster

Comment: There's no inside vs outside, though if all write requests are hitting S3. You can very easily do that, though. In fact, we do it for months at a time with daily datasets streaming in from Kafka... Spark, Hive, or Presto are very capable of that processing pattern, and don't necessarily require "core Hadoop" because all files are being loaded from S3 storage, as mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180776/discussion-between-pat-and-cricket-007).